# Windows form is not displaying in csharp when i run the code

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a databse using access, and all of a sudden, when I run the code, my form is not showing. It was displaying the form just a while ago but now it is not. I did not touch or mess with the program.cs file, by the way.
Below is the program.cs file:

```
namespace P1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

    }
}
```

Below is my database code, if it helps. I have even cut down some code but it is not showing the form at all. However, it is showing that the program is build with no errors.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace P1
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {          
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =d:\DDBS.mdb");
        OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =d:\DDBS.mdb","select * from Student");
        DataTable d2 = new DataTable();
        DataSet d1 = new DataSet("Student");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();               
            
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dDBSDataSet.Student' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            //this.studentTableAdapter.Fill(this.dDBSDataSet.Student);

        }

        private void display_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            adap.Fill(d2);
            dataGrid3.DataSource = d2;
        }
        private void dataGrid1_Navigate(object sender, NavigateEventArgs ne)
        {
        }
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void form2_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
        }

        private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 f3 = new Form3();
            f3.Show();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form4 f4 = new Form4();
            f4.Show();
        }

        private void next_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void dataGrid2_Navigate(object sender, NavigateEventArgs ne)
        {

        }

        private void dataGrid3_Navigate(object sender, NavigateEventArgs ne)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The setting output type of form:
[image: The setting output type of form]

Comment: Remove `this.Show()` from Form1_Load. It's not needed. The form that is given to `Application.Run` is automatically shown.

Comment: Try moving the initializations of `con`, `adap`, `d2`, and `d1` inside the `Form1` constructor, after the `InitializeComponent` call.  Then set a breakpoint at the beginning of the `Form1` constructor.  Does it get called?  Does it execute all the statements without throwing an exception?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've commented out the line that shows the form. In your bottom sample code there's a `Form1_Load` method, the line above the `TODO` is the line you'd want.

Comment: I already commented it out before but it still did not fix the problem, form still didn't show up.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly show the form given to `Application.Run`, it will be shown automatically.

Comment: Fair enough, in that case I'll watch the question because I'm curious now - I can't see anything else that stands out.

Comment: Thank you, but don't look too much into it. I will probably create a new project after a while now, lol.

Comment: Umm, so i cleared all the code from buttons and the form load event, also cleared all the connections i made to the database and now the form is showing. This is weird

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is your setting output type is Console Application or Class Library. You should change is to Application Form.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DNmL.png)

Comment: As long as he's producing an executable, you can show a form, this even from a console application, so that's not it.

Comment: No, it is set to application form.